# How can i add href dynamic inside <link> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to display the favicon in the angular 2, i have implemented by putting these lines

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="app/favicon.ico" />
```

But, in this there is a problem i need to refresh my page and on 2nd time on a new browser its displaying the favicon. But, i want favicon to refresh forcefully and for that i am using

```
<link rel="icon" href=http://domainname+"/favicon.ico?v=2"/>
```

> For this i need to populate the domain name dynamically

and also i am getting the host name by using the below code

```
  <script>
    var url = window.location.href
    console.log('Main Loaded '+url);
  </script>
```

Now i want url to be placed inside the href of link where domain name is there .
Please suggest how i can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the href directly like that, because document.getElementsByTagName returns all the  tags (as a NodeList). If you're positive you only have one, use this:

```
var findlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
findlink[0].href = url;
```

If you have multiple link elements and want to target a specific one, give it an id and use `document.getElementById`:

```
var findlink = document.getElementsById("myLinkId");
findlink.href = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

The href of the link can be set dynamically. You have to identify the link and set the href attribute of the element like the following code,

```
window.document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].href = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` will return the full path.
So use `window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host` to get the domain

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].href=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/favicon.ico?v=2";
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0]);
```

```html
<link rel="icon" href=http://domainname+"/favicon.ico?v=2"/>
```

To see the difference, run it here

```js
console.log(window.location.href);
console.log(window.location.protocol);
console.log(window.location.host);
```